# Removing stopwords from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

The list below is generated by stemmer and includes the most common words in a document.

```
list=[('d', 438),
 ('ricc', 308),
 ('cas', 256),
 ('sal', 237),
 ('nuov', 206),
 ('cos', 203),
 ('immunitar', 202),
 ('prim', 193),
 ('mineral', 192),
 ('molt', 172),
 ('frutt', 167),
 ('aliment', 164),
 ('b', 164)]
```

However, it includes single letters that should be excluded using a stopwords list. I would like to remove these words (I am using Italian stopwords). I have tried as follows:

```
it_stopwords= set(stopwords.words('italian'))
highest =counts.most_common()[:20]
highest = [w for w in highest if not w in it_stopwords]
```

but no words have been removed from the list. I think because it is a dictionary and the code above could not be applied.

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. I don't see any pandas here--is the tag appropriate? What might be happening (total speculation since the example isn't complete) is that `w` is a tuple, so you may need `w[0] not in it_stopwords`. Thanks.

Comment: Apparently, 'b' & 'd' are not in the Italian list of stopwords.  The single-letter stopwords for Italian are: `['è', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'l', 'a', 'o']`.  Are 'b' and 'd' actually the stem of Italian words?  Do you want to get rid of all single letter words regardless of being a stopword?

Comment: @DarrylG, you're right. I created my own list of stopwords to include them

Comment: @LucaDiMauro--great.  FYI an easy way to include is: `italian_stopwords = set(stopwords.words('italian')).union(['b', 'd'])` where stopwords is: `from nltk.corpus import stopwords `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is a list of tuples, not words. So:

```
highest = [w for w in highest if not w[0] in it_stopwords]
```

However, the stopwords will just be removed from the 20 most common elements, so your final result will probably have less than 20 items.

If you want 20 items **after** removing the stop words, then you should update your `counts.most_common` function with a `stop_words` kwarg.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use shadow built-in names like `list`, it can make bad things happen. If you want you can use `_list` which is a valid alternative as a calling convention.
Then, you can still write a custom function and use it into a filter call:

```
def delete_stopwords(word):
    it_stopwords = set(stopwords.words('italian'))
    if word in it_stopwords:
     return False
    return True

filterList = filter(delete_stopwords,_list)
```

NB the function I wrote is not the fastest one, but it should work, you may want to write your own function by for instance creating the set just once. I also don't know the library you used to generate the stopwords but it will probably work smoothly even without the explicit build to `set`.

Comment: Good advice, but consider using `return word in set(stopwords.words("italian"))` instead of the `if..return true.. return false`. Also, this isn't a `cast` to set, it's building a `set` object from a list. Good point that if you're only doing one lookup, there's no point in making a set. That'd need to be a one-off setup expense.

Comment: I have left the example as it is since it is thought to show how filter work and put out the cast word. Thank you for your corrections